# Cannot access 'filter': it is internal in 'kotlinx.coroutines.channels'

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, deprecation-warning

Methods "map" and "filter" have been deprecated with the upgrade of Kotlin Coroutine Version. Code was working perfectly fine with earlier version of Kotlin Coroutine, due to some reason I need to upgrade coroutine version. But having much idea about it.

`````
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.BroadcastChannel
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ReceiveChannel
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.filter
import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.map

object EventBus {
    @ObsoleteCoroutinesApi
    val bus: BroadcastChannel<Any> = BroadcastChannel(1)

    @ObsoleteCoroutinesApi
    fun send(o: Any) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            bus.send(o)
        }
    }

    @ObsoleteCoroutinesApi
    inline fun <reified T> asChannel(): ReceiveChannel<T> {
        return bus.openSubscription().filter { it is T }.map { it as T }
    }
}````


Can we replace the above usage of Map and Filter? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
`````

Answer (score 3):

You should take annotation `@ObsoleteCoroutinesApi` serious, because
class [`BroadcastChannel`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-broadcast-channel/index.html) had been deprecated altogether ...instead use [`SharedFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/index.html) or [`MutableSharedFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-state-flow/index.html); also see this [example](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#sharedflow).
This blog post should support the understanding & migration: [Shared flows, broadcast channels](https://elizarov.medium.com/shared-flows-broadcast-channels-899b675e805c).